# freezes when uploading something

Tags: release-jolnir

when i upload a video, picture or something like that on web, elementary os freezing. Waiting does not solve the problem. I have to shut down the computer and then restart it. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Same issue since 1st February. Error report sent twice after restart

I'm uploading a screenshot, fingers crossed that the computer doesn't crash ;)

[image: German error message after restart...]

My first assumptions were Google Chromium via snapcraft.io or my notebook's Nvidia graphics card drivers could be causing the problem.

In the meantime I've even bought a desktop PC, but the same problem there with elementary OS 6.1 Jólnir.